# javascript variable changed in async callback

Tags: javascript

```
  a = ["1","2","3"]
  square = (i,cb)->
    i = parseInt(i)
    setTimeout ()->cb null,i*i,100
  for i in a
    square i,(err,result)->
      console.log i + " " + result

    output:
    3 1
    3 4
    3 9
    expected:
    1 1
    2 4
    3 9
```

if remove setTimeout I can get expected result.

or write like this

```
    for i in a
      ((i)->
        square i,(err,result)->
          console.log i + " " + result
      )(i)
```

Is this a javascript bug?

Comment: Is this a javascript code? can you create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: What is that? CoffeeScript, Typescript? It's not JavaScript.

Comment: That output is not a bug, its how async works. By the time your timeout calls are triggered the for loop has already finished. So `i` holds the last value used in the loop, in this case 3, so 3 is outputted each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same code in actual javascript, that produces the same result (and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99obrntp/)

```
var a = ['1','2','3'];

function square(i, cb){
    i = parseInt(i);
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb(null, i*i);
    }, 100);
}

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    var value = a[i];
    square(value, function(err, result){
        console.log(value, result);
    });
}
```

Now the squared result is obviously correct, but the problem is your call to `console.log()`. The reason being is that the callback will not be called for the first time until the loop has completed (because of `setTimeout`). In other words the `value` becomes `3` before the console is written to for the first time. To fix this, you need to pass the value through to your callback. For example:

```
var a = ['1','2','3'];

function square(i, cb){
    i = parseInt(i);
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb(null, i*i, i);
    }, 100);
}

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    var value = a[i];
    square(value, function(err, result, initial){
        console.log(initial, result);
    });
}
```

Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3sdjgzv1/